# Pytorch 2D convolution is somewhat slow

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch, conv-neural-network, convolution

I am trying to replace a single 2D convolution layer with a relatively large kernel, with several 2D-Conv layers having much smaller kernels. Theoretically, the replacement should work much faster (in respect of the number of operations) but actually it does not.

Suppose my kernel is of size OxCxHxW (output channels, input channels, height, width, respectfully), then in theory, the computational cost is `OxCxHxW` per input pixel. However, it seems that larger kernels are computed much faster.

For example:

1. a kernel of size  32x32x5x5 takes 46ms to run (baseline large kernel)
2. a smaller kernel of size 32x32x1x1 takes 8 ms (supposed to be x25 faster than #1, about 2ms)
3. a group-convolution with a kernel size of 32x1x5x5 takes about 9 ms, while the reduction in kernel size is much more significant (supposed to be x32 faster than #1, about 1.5ms).

I have also tried TensorFlow and got similar results.

I understand that larger kernels probably utilize the CPU (or GPU) better and that there is a function's call overhead, but the time reduction going from large to the small kernel is not as significant as I expected.

A colab notebook can be found [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1pge7OADYx6soaHm2y7WXBmlFKV5SV077?usp=sharing).

Can anyone suggest an idea to accelerate those small convolutions?

Comment: I've run into this before with larger, large relative to DL conv sizes, convolutions. fftw is pretty much the go-to fast CPU library. That being said, scipy is almost as quick if I remember my old tests right. By the way, your theoretical time complexity isn't right. Larger convolutions are easily sped up with FFT algorithms and smaller convolutions on GPU have a lot of tricks too.

Comment: Yeah, I was referring to small kernels, which are the more common ones. As for scipy - I chose Pytorch since it's part of a neural network and running it on a GPU is straightforward. So for large kernels you implemented it yourself using FFTW?

Comment: I guess, "small" and "large" are relative terms. I don't have the analysis I did anymore, but I remember somewhere around kernel size of ~15 that pytorch was slower than scipy or fftw. They were supposed to be working on support for larger kernels, but as you've found it must not have happened. e.g. https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/21462 https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/pytorch-for-larger-convolutions-slow/32176/5